# Связь сертификатов и профайлов с существующим в App Store приложением

Tags: xcode, appstore

Остаётся ли у приложения, загруженного в App Store, какая-то связь с сертификатами и provisioning профайлами?

Другими словами, если, после загрузки приложения в App Store зайти в аккаунт организации и удалить все имеющиеся там сертификаты: Development , Distribution, APNs Development, Apple Push Services, а также все provisioning профайлы: Development и Distribution, будет ли приложение скачанное и установленное на устройствах пользователей (как до так и после этого удаления), работать без проблем?

И если ответ - да, без проблем, то как следствие, следующий вопрос: а если  после всего этого создать заново все нужные новые сертификаты и provisioning профайлы, собрать уже с ними новую версию этого же приложения и загрузить её в App Store, то старая версия, будучи до этого установленной на устройствах пользователей, и после этого по-прежнему будет работать без проблем?

Comment: не скажу точно, но поидее должно все быть нормально если их удалить они(серитификаты) уже есть в билде который качают люди, и с новыми мертификатами не должно быть проблем они ведь делаются на appID, + у сертификатов есть строк годности (можно посмотреть когда истекает)

Comment: @AndreyIskamov, думаете, удаление даже Apple Push Services сертификата не будет проблемой?

Comment: Ну я не сталкивался с таким вопросом, это только мысли )